# jQuery AJAX returns 200 OK status, but errors. How can I view details of error?

Tags: jquery, error-handling

I have the following jQuery:

```
var fn = {
    Load: function () {
        $(".myclass input.Submit").click(function (e) {
            var _IsValid = fn.IsValid();
            if (_IsValid == false) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            //Popup displays message fine if "return false;" is
            //called here but then obviously never posts back.
        });
    }
, IsValid: function () {

    var _IsValid = true;
$.ajax({
       url: "/myURL"
       , type: 'POST'
       , contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        , data: JSON.stringify({ Barcode: $barcode.val(), Email: $email.val() })
        , dataType: 'json'
       , success: function (data) {
          var array = eval(data);
          if (array[0] == 0) {
            _IsValid = false;
            ShowPopup(array[1]);
          }
         }
       , error: function (xhr, status, error) {

         }
    });
   return _IsValid;
 }
}
```

AJAX response is `200 OK`, but the `success` function is not being ran. Instead it seems to be running the `error` function.

The script is being ran as an click event listener for an ASP.NET ImageButton. If `_IsValid==false`, then `e.preventDefault()` is invoked to prevent postback.

What's strange is that if I add return false to the end of my event listener function, this code runs the `success` function.

How can I find out what is causing this to error so that I can resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you currently have is that your `IsValid` function will always return true. This is because the AJAX post will not have time to complete before the function is returned. It is an asynchronous function after all.

From what I can tell you want to valid a form with an AJAX request and if valid submit the form, otherwise show a popup. If that is correct you should do something like...

```
$(".myclass input.Submit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ProcessForm();
});

function ProcessForm(){
   $.ajax({
       url: "/myURL"
       , type: 'POST'
       , contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        , data: JSON.stringify({ Barcode: $barcode.val(), Email: $email.val() })
        , dataType: 'json'
       , success: function (data) {
          var array = eval(data);
          if (array[0] == 0) {
            ShowPopup(array[1]);
          }
          else//VALID
          {
             document.forms[0].submit();
             //OR IF YOU HAVE MULTIPLE FORMS SPECIFY AN ID...
             document.getElementById("FormElement").submit();
          }
         }
       , error: function (xhr, status, error) {

         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I find out what is causing this to error so that I can resolve it?

You could use a javascript debugging tool in your browser such as FireBug in FireFox which will allow you to see the AJAX request and response. You will see exactly what's sent over the wire and any possible errors.

In fact looking at this:

```
dataType: 'json;'
```

you probably meant:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

When you explicitly set the response content type like this you should make sure that the server sends valid JSON as jQuery will attempt to parse the response and if it fails you will get an exception.

Also I would totally replace:

```
data: '{"Barcode":"' + $barcode.val() + '", "Email":"' + $email.val() + '"}'
```

with:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ Barcode: $barcode.val(), Email: $email.val() })
```

Never use string concatenations like as you did when building JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've made the changes you recommended, and its still erroring. Furthermore, I've tried debugging the javascript in Google Chrome. `xhr.ResponseText = ""`. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion was to look at the Network tab where you see the AJAX requests and Responses. But in this case if the server sent an empty response and you explicitly set `dataType: 'json'`, well, you know, `''` is an invalid JSON. So you might try to fix your server to send valid JSON.

Comment: I've also updated my question with a bit more information regarding the application

Comment: server is sending valid JSON. Its returning `[false,"Barcode 123 does not exist"]`. Pretty certain this is valid JSON

Comment: @Curt, indeed, it's valid JSON. Is it the response you see in the Network tab? Did you fix the `dataType: 'json;'` issue with your code?

Comment: The response in the network tab is blank. But this doesn't happen when `return false` is added later on in the code (as I added in my edit in the question). How does this make any sense? Yes I've corrected `json`, I've updated the script in the question to show what is being used now.

Comment: If the response is blank in the Network tab it means there's a problem with your server side code. What might explain the discrepancy you observe between `return false` and `e.preventDefault()` is the fact that you forgot to define the `e` variable and so when you attempt to call preventDefault you get js error. This variable is normally passed as argument to the click handler. Unfortunately as you haven't shown your code it's very difficult for me to help you further. Look at your javascript debugging tool. Look at the Console. It will definitely contain answers to your problems.

Comment: I've posted some more of my javascript. This should explain my use of `e.preventDefault`.